# How to redirect from one view to another view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, navigation, swiftui

I am using `SwiftUI`. I'm trying to move from list to details of a particular row of list. I've used code written below

```swift
struct StudentList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(studentData) { student in
                NavigationLink(destination: studentDetail()) {
                    studentRow(student: student)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Student Details"))
        }
    }
}

struct StudentList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StudentsList()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
 List(studentData) { student in
     NavigationLink.init("Here Title", destination:  studentDetail())
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {

  let items = [1,2,3,4,5]
  var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
      List(items, id: \.self) { inx in
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(inx: inx)) {
            Text("\(inx)")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    var  inx : Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(inx)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NavigationLink(destination: "provide your view here") {

                    }
```